# How to shut down socket server?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

My server code looks like this:

```
def start_server(port, serverip):
    global serverThread, server
    server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((serverip, port))
    serverThread=threading.Thread(target=start)
    serverThread.start()

def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        try:
            con, addres= server.accept()
            users.append(con)
            addreses.append(addres)
            cn= threading.Thread(target=connection, args=(con, addres))
            cn.start()
        except:
            break
```

I tried to shutdown It like this

```
server.shutdown(1)
server.close()
```

but I get [WinError 10057].
How should I do It?

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387712/python-sockets-how-to-shut-down-the-server

Comment: I changed my code and get same error as before.

Comment: 10057 isn't really an error in this instance - it just means the socket is disconnected. As the application is closing, the socket instance is torn down when it stops listening. The first thing that does is disconnect it. I wouldn't regard it as an error, more as part of the process of the app shutting down.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> server.shutdown(1)
> server.close()
> ```
>
> but I get [WinError 10057]. How should I do It?

shutdown is about shutting down parts or all of a connection. So you cannot shutdown anything which is not connected in the first place. The listener socket is not connected, hence WSAENOTCONN (10057). Just close the socket, don't shutdown.

Comment: That is true for the listening `server` socket, however you should `shutdown()` and `close()` the sockets that `server.accept()` returned.